# \bibliographystyle doesn't apply

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

`\bibliographystyle` doesn't seem to be applied.
I want to get

> Майоров С.А., Новиков Г.И. Принципы организации цифровых машин. - Л.: Машиностроение, 1974. - 432 с.

but I'm getting

> Новиков Г.И. Майоров С.А. Принципы организации цифровых машин. Машиностроение, Л., 1974.

instead.

Style used to format as showed on the first example is in `gost71u.bst` file. I even tried to copy this file to directory where `.tex` file located. Here is the code

```tex
\makeatletter
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    % blah blah

    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Список литературы}
    \bibliographystyle{gost780u}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{Список литературы}
    \bibliography{cites}

\end{document}
```

Also there are some extra styles: `gost780s`, `gost71s`, `gost780u`, but they are not applying too.

I'm using the sequence of commands described [there](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.html): at first I'm running pdflatex and then — bibtex. And it worked only once.

Comment: Does it help if you remove the initial `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` statement?

Comment: it would probably be helpful if you included the `.bib` input with your question.

Answer (score 2):

I updated my latex packages and found that there are no `gost71*` files (but don't know why it didn't work *before* update). There are new standards which should be used with `gost2003*` and `gost2008*` styles.